# How to set breakpoint on user defined PHP functions with dbg?

Tags: php, c

I can break on built-in functions like `preg_replace` by break on `php_pcre_replace`,

but my own function(`function func(){...}`),how can I set breakpoint on it?

Comment: Can't Zend debugger do the trick ?

Answer (score 0):

If your function is defined in the PHP interpreter itself, and is basically interpreted and evaluated at run-time rather than being a pre-complied C-based plug-in, then you're not going to have access to it from gdb unless you were going to step through the actual PHP interpreter execution loop itself, and even then, I'm not sure how you would know exactly when it was your function being called.  Some possibilities that could work are either monitoring all calls to PHP's `execute()`, or possibly issue a `SIGTRAP` using `posix_kill` and `posix_getpid` on the PHP processes itself inside your function in order to stop gdb at the point when your function executes.  The built-in functions on the other-hand are actually implemented in C, so when the interpreter calls those functions, it is making a call into compiled code, and therefore can easily have breakpoints set in gdb.

So for instance, adding this line inside your PHP function (probably right at the start)

```
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGTRAP);
```

should stop the PHP process you're monitoring with gdb at the point-of-call, which would be inside your user-defined PHP function in the interpreter.  Depending on your OS, the value of SIGTRAP may not be defined, so you may have to look in your OS's signal.h file to see what signal values would be appropriate.  But SIGTRAP is available on any POSIX-compliant OS.

Finally, be sure to remove this line when you are not using gdb, otherwise you'll just terminate the PHP process running your script when the signal is raised.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say impossible ... I did add a note on a possibility where you can issue a `SIGTRAP` signal to the PHP process running your script that will stop gdb at the point where your user-defined function executes.  You're still going to have to be familiar with PHP's internal data-structures though in order to properly step through your function's execution.

Comment: @Jason,can you explain in more detail how monitoring `execute()` and `SIGTRAP` will achieve my goal?

Comment: @Jason,ah,I see ,so I need the modify the function to include `(posix_getpid(), SIGTRAP); `

Comment: What about the way you mentioned using `execute()`?

Comment: I think that method is going to be too complex ... and when you issue the SIGTRAP and stop gdb, you'll be inside of `execute()` anyways since the PHP interpreter always calls `execute()` internally when executing a user-defined function.